# How to mail PDF when using Chrome PDF viewer?

Tags: google-chrome, email, pdf

I have a new PC and noticed that chrome has a built in PDF viewer that seems to be light weight and decided it seems good enough to avoid acrobat reader download and installation.

I now realized I need to be able to email documents as an attachment. I cannot send a link because there might be times that I do not want to have the recipient see where the PDF comes from.

Is it possible to mail pdf when using Chrome PDF viewer directly from the browser or should I just install Acrobat Reader?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Chrome extension; Email PDF for Chrome PDF Viewer 1.3.0:

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jcanbebjhbcobnnmbbcljaehnimiikgg

It uses Gmail API to email PDF directly from Chrome PDF viewer.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for **minimum required information** and suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  To keep your answer useful even if the provided link(s) breaks these details should be edited into your answer.

Comment: The user does not want to use gmail but instead use the native mail program installed on the machine.

Comment: Please edit your question and make it clear that you wish to use native maill program. @Nightwolf